# Popup in my chrome extension is tiny and does not show data

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popup

I'm coding a Chrome extension that would show a popup, but I cannot manage to control the size of content and only one tiny pixel shows.

Here is a screenshot, for reference:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see the two gradient pixels are scroll bars and the one black pixel is the information.

**Edit: Would it work instead with fixed or relative positioning?**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
    <style type="text/css"> 
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-family: MyriadPro-Regular, 'Myriad Pro Regular', MyriadPro, 'Myriad Pro', 
Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.profile_tab {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 12px;
}

.settings_tab {
  position: absolute;
  top: 124px;
  left: 12px;
}

.news_tab {
  position: absolute;
  top: 218px;
  left: 12px;
}

    </style>
    <script></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div 
  class="profile_tab"> <img src="images/Profile_Tab.png"> 
</div>
<div 
  class="settings_tab"> <img src="images/Settings_Tab.gif"> 
</div>
<div 
  class="news_tab"> <img src="images/News_Tab.gif">
</div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome on SO. Please provide us with code. Otherwise, it's not clear what you are asking and this question may be put on hold soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of the popup is determined from the width/height of the root element, `<html>`, also known as `document.documentElement`.

When an element is absolutely positioned, it's removed from the document's flow. Consequently, the width/height of the element does not contribute to the width/height of the parent elements.

To solve the issue, you can do one or all of the following:

- Do not use `position:absolute`.
- Assign a fixed width/height to the root element (through CSS).
- Use JavaScript to calculate the width/height of the greatest element, and assign the result to `document.documentElement.style.width` and `.height`. The most generic method (=looping through all elements and calculating their bottom/right offset using [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect)) is quite expensive. Because you probably know in advance how your page looks like, you will be able to create a more effective method. For example: select the biggest element and read its `.scrollHeight` or `.offsetHeight` properties.

Comment: Could you please suggest a way that I would use something other than absolute? I am very new to web development and I made a PSD frame that I cut up and used `position:absolute` to align each image up with the others. Should I make a table? or do you have another way of doing this that you think is better? Thanks!

Comment: In your specific case, setting a `width` for the divs will be sufficient. You might also want to use `margin` to add more space between the elements.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create an empty div that I gave a height and a width too in CSS. You can see what I did here:

```
CSS:

.content {
  width: 470px;
  height: 330px;
}

HTML:

<div class="content">  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

include the body thing in container. 
Set height and width to container.

```
//Css code
#container{
width:250px;
height:300px;
background-color:FFFFFF;
border-width:1px;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

//html code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
</head>
<div id="container">
<body>
...
</body>
<div>
</html>
```